# Apache Worker and Prefork both defined

Tags: apache-2.2

The following is a segment from a current Apache installation I'm attempting to decipher for bad performance. I noticed the below, both uncommented:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          200
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          150
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

When prefork and worker are both defined, what happens? We're using PHP, so I assume that prefork would be what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When prefork and worker are both defined, what happens? We're using
>   PHP, so I assume that prefork would be what we want.

Exactly. You can confirm with:

```
# apachectl -l
```

or

```
# httpd -V
```

Comment: `apache2 -V` shows `-D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"`. Thanks!

Comment: if you are using apache2 - apache2ctl -l  (part of the apache2.X-common package on Ubuntu)